# Wait for messages processed by Service Bus OnMessage to finish

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm using the Azure Service Bus SubscriptionClient.OnMessage method; configured to process up to 5 messages concurrently.

Within the code I need to wait for all messages to finish processing before I can continue (to properly shutdown an Azure Worker Role). How do I do this?

Will SubscriptionClient.Close() block until all messages have finished processing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling Close on SubscriptionClient or QueueClient will not block.  Calling Close closes off the entity immediately as far as I can tell.  I tested quickly just using the Worker Role With Service Bus Queue project template that shipped with Windows Azure SDK 2.0.  I added a thread sleep for many seconds in the message process action and then shut down the role while it was running.  I saw the Close method get called while the messages were processing in their thread sleep but it certainly did not wait for the for message processing to complete, the role simple closed down.

To handle this gracefully you'll need to do the same thing we did when dealing with any worker role that was processing messages (Service Bus, Azure Storage queue or anything else): keep track of what is being worked on and shut down when it is complete.  There are several ways to deal with that but all of them are manual and made messy in this case because of the multiple threads involved.

Given the way that OnMessage works you'll need to add something in the action that looks to see if the role has been told to shutdown, and if so, to not do any processing.  The problem is, when the OnMessage action is executed it HAS a message already.  You'd probably need to abandon the message but not exit the OnMessage action, otherwise it will keep getting a message if there are ones in the queue.  You can't simply abandon the message and let the execution leave the action because then the system will be handed another message (possibly the same one) and several threads doing this may cause messages to get too many dequeue counts and get dead lettered.  Also, you can't call Close on the SubscriptionClient or QueueClient, which would stop the receive loop internally, because once you call close any of the outstanding message processing will throw an exception when .Complete, .Abandon, etc. is called on the message because the message entity is now closed.  This means you can't stop the incoming messages easily.

The main issue here is because you are using the OnMessage and setting up the concurrent message handling by setting the MaxConcurrentCalls on the OnMessageOptions, which means the code that starts and manages the threads is buried in the QueueClient and SubscriptionClient and you don't have control over that.  You don't have a way to reduce the count of threads, or stop the threads individually, etc.  You'll need to create a way to put the OnMessage action threads into a state where they are aware that the system is being told to shut down and then complete their message and not exit the action in order for them to not continuously be assigned new messages.  This means you'll likely need to also set the MessageOptions to not use autocomplete and manually call complete in your OnMessage action.

Having to do all of this may severely reduce the actual benefit of using the OnMessage helper.  Behind the scenes OnMessage is simply setting up a loop calling receive with the default timeout and handing of messages to another thread to do the action (loose description).  So what you get by using the OnMessage approach is away from having to write that handler on your own, but then the problem you are having is because you didn't write that handler on your own you don't have control over those threads. Catch-22. If you really need to stop gracefully you may want to step away from the OnMessage approach, write your own Receive loop with threading and within the main loop stop receiving new messages and wait for all the workers to end.

One option, especially if the messages are idempotent (which means processing them more than once yields the same results... which you should be mindful of anyway) then if they are stopped in mid processing they will simply reappear on the queue to be processed by another instance later.  If the work itself isn't resource intensive and the operations are idempotent then this really can be an option.  No different than when an instance might fail due to hardware failure or other issues.  Sure, it's not graceful or elegant, but it certainly removes all the complexity I've mentioned and is still something that can happen anyway due to other failures.

Note that the OnStop is called when an instance is told to shut down.  You've got 5 minutes you can delay this until the fabric just shuts it off, so if your messages take longer than five minutes to process it won't really matter if you attempt to shut down gracefully or not, some will be cut off during processing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll take your suggestion and just write the loop myself. I was hoping the OnMessage method would be a good shortcut to multiple threads but it looks like it will be more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: I've sent feedback to the Product Group about this and I've also posted this to the Windows Azure User Voice as an idea. http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/216926-service-bus/suggestions/4345733-provide-gracefull-shutdown-feature-to-message-pump  Please vote it up if you'd like to see it.

Answer (score 3):

You can tweak OnMessageAsync to wait for processing of messages to complete, and block new messages from beginning to be processed:

Here is the implementation:

```
_subscriptionClient.OnMessageAsync(async message =>
        {
            if (_stopRequested)
            {
                // Block processing of new messages. We want to wait for old messages to complete and exit.
                await Task.Delay(_waitForExecutionCompletionTimeout);                   
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    // Track executing messages
                    _activeTaskCollection[message.MessageId] = message;

                    await messageHandler(message);
                    await message.CompleteAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // handle error by disposing or doing nothing to force a retry
                }
                finally
                {
                    BrokeredMessage savedMessage;

                    if (!_activeTaskCollection.TryRemove(message.MessageId, out savedMessage))
                    {
                        _logger.LogWarning("Attempt to remove message id {0} failed.", savedMessage.MessageId);
                    }
                }
            }

        }, onMessageOptions);
```

And an implementation of Stop that waits for completion:

```
  public async Task Stop()
    {
        _stopRequested = true;
        DateTime startWaitTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        while (DateTime.UtcNow - startWaitTime < _waitForExecutionCompletionTimeout && _activeTaskCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(_waitForExecutionCompletionSleepBetweenIterations);
        }

        await _subscriptionClient.CloseAsync();
        }
```

Note that _activeTaskCollection is a ConcurrentDictionary (we can also use a counter with interlock to count the number of in progress messages, but using a dictionary allows you to investigate what happend easily in case of errors.

Comment: Thanks for tip. I've implemented similar just with using of TaskCompletionSource and CountdownEvent. Each message handler increments event on starting and signals on completing.
`if (_messagePumpStoppingSource != null)
{
_log.Warning("Listener is closing. Deferring message...");
await _messagePumpStoppingSource.Task;
return;
}`

once all handlers have signalled in Stop method I have
`_countdownEvent.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
await Task.WhenAll(_clients.Select(x => x.CloseAsync()));
_messagePumpStoppingSource.SetResult(true);`